# How do you tell how many USB hosts a motherboard has?

Tags: usb, motherboard, bandwidth

I am building a system which will act as a hub for compressing and saving video streams from a dozen USB cameras. Each camera will stream at a bit under 800 Mbit/s so a single USB 3.0 host (5 Gbit/s) is insufficient. I am aware of--and will likely use--PCIe USB 3.0 expansion cards, but is there any way to tell from a motherboard's listed specs how many separate hosts it has? Or is it fair to assume that every motherboard has all of its USB ports connected to a single host?

Comment: This will have to be deduced or noted from the documentation for the main board. The user manual will not likely contain this, but there are often technical specification documents which will note the specific components. However, this information will also vary as there is no standard specifying that this has to be presented in a particular document or manner.

Comment: What are you using, 8k cameras?

Comment: @SamForbis only 1280x800, but 12-bit/60fps

Comment: Most usb controllers are part of the chipset or processor with integrated chipset, my Dell motherboard uses the Intel 8 series/C220 host controller (usb 2.0) which has 2 independent controllers, and one usb 3.0 (found using device manager), so you would have to do some internet digging about the chipset or processor for any particular motherboard.

Comment: 800 Mbps sounds high even for 12-bit video... Are you sure the cameras don't send pre-encoded video to the PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or is it fair to assume that every motherboard has all of its USB
>   ports connected to a single host?

No. It was true for mainboards/processors about 10 years ago. Modern systems like AMD Ryzen 2xxx and 3xxx usually have 3 USB 3.x host controllers. Most recent boards (AMD X570) have 3 USB 3.2 host controllers operating at Gen2 10 Gbps speed, two hosts inside the core CPU, and one resides in South Bridge. If you are using USB 3.0 devices, you can have ~2400 MBytes/s aggregate stream.

Many hi-end Intel mobos can have 3-4 host USB 3.0 controllers, usually two on ICH hub, and one or two add-on ASMxx42-based chips sitting on board's PCIe bus.

The lowest in the ASUS line of AMD Threadripper 3xxx series (PRIME TRX40 PRO) has four USB 3.2 Gen2 controllers.

In short, it all depends on manufacturer, and unfortunately the parameter of how many independent USB hosts is implemented is not on marketing list.